# SSRS - Keep a table the same width when hiding columns dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

Greetings.

I have a SSRS 2005 report that shows prices of things.  For some customers, I hide a column from the table (with an expression on the Visibility - hidden property).

When I do this, my table shrinks.  I've searched long and hard for a way to dynamically resize this table (or to do something at design time to make it stay the same width), but I'm stuck.

Answers that simply state 'You can't do this' won't help me.  I've read that already:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1354956.aspx

I'm hoping that some smart soul of the SO community has a workaround for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you want all columns to be resized so that it covers the entire table when a specific column is invisible?

Comment: That would work.  I would settle with resizing 1 or 2 of the columns.  I just need the table to be the same width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I know how to accomplish this, is by altering your RDLC file during runtime.  Basically, you can load up your RLDC file into memory (its just an XML file), locate the XML node that contains the width of your table - then modify the setting in memory.  Once you have done that, you can refresh your reportViewer control using the RDLC file that is loaded in memory.

And yes, I have already done this, and it does work.

The following code example is to alter the data of an RDLC file in memory, via its XMLpath.

```
  Private Sub ModifyRDLCInMemory()

    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    Dim asm As Reflection.Assembly = Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    'create in memory, a XML file from a embedded resource
    Dim xmlStream As Stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource)

    Try
      'Load the RDLC file into a XML doc
      xmlDoc.Load(xmlStream)
    Catch e As Exception
      MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
    End Try

    'Create an XmlNamespaceManager to resolve the default namespace
    Dim nsmgr As XmlNamespaceManager = New XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable)
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("nm", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition")
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("rd", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner")

    'Loop through each node in the XML file
    Dim node As XmlNode
    For Each node In xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(String.Format("//nm:{0}[@rd:LocID]", "Value"), nsmgr)  'XPath to LocID node.. You will want to change this to locate your Table Width node. You may need to read up on XMLPath
      Dim nodeValue As String = node.InnerText  'Gets current value of Node
      If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nodeValue) Or Not nodeValue.StartsWith("=")) Then
        Try
          node.InnerText = YOURNEWVALUE

        Catch ex As Exception
          'handle error
        End Try
      End If
    Next

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = String.Empty
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = Nothing
    'Load the updated RDLC document into LocalReport object.
    Dim rdlcOutputStream As StringReader = New StringReader(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml)
    Using rdlcOutputStream
      ReportViewer1.LocalReport.LoadReportDefinition(rdlcOutputStream)
    End Using

  End Sub
```

Comment: Very interesting take on the problem.  I'm going to give it another hour or so and if no one shows up with a better solution I'll mark you as answer.  Thanks!

Comment: I can past some VB.NET code to help you out if you want.. I will right now actually.

Comment: Code Posted. Let me know if you have any questions about it.  We used to localize our reports with this method (altering the data when the language was switched).  We are now generating our reports dynamically, so we don't use this anymore.

Comment: Thanks for this example.  I quickly implemented parser to conditionally change width of Tablix and Rectangle columns.  I will also take you up on the idea of localizing texts.  Using separate reports for each locale is sometimes fine but when you have dynamic texts you need dynamic report texts as well.  Doing this externally is more effective than supplying report-inline functionality… and you can use proper programming language like C# 

Answer (score 0):

The best choice is to duplicate the table and put in above the other with the columns you want to show. Then you can set the visibility of the table dinamycallly. In order to make them editable you put one table a little smaller thant the other to select it when it is above one.

Answer (score 0):

Prior answers make this harder than it needs to be. In addition to the column you will be conditionally hiding, decide which other column(s) should get wider when that column is hidden and by how much they should grow. Usually, I just give the extra width of the hidden column to one of the other columns in the report, we'll call that the "Grow Column". Add an additional column immediately to the left or right of Grow Column. Make the width of this new column the width of Grow Column plus the width of the column that will be hidden. Set the new column(s) content identically to Grow Column. Set the visibility of Grow Column the same as the column you will be hiding. Set the visibility of the wider copy of Grow Column inverse to the visibility of Grow Column. Now, when you hide your optional column, the wider version of Grow Column will display and the narrow version of Grow Column will be hidden. Thus maintaining the width of the table and making one column wider.