# SSRS: adjusting report and page size at runtime

Tags: reporting-services

Basically I'm trying to get a png back from SSRS 2008, which will go into a cell of variable size, which is determined when making the request. So my inquiry boils down to these 3 questions:

1. Is there any way to specify the page size of the report with web request parameters or through a web service call?
2. Can I tell a chart to fill the page instead of giving it fixed size parameters?
3. Barring these two items, is there another way around the issue?

Answer (score 0):

See my post here:
[SSRS - Keep a table the same width when hiding columns dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440381/ssrs-keep-a-table-the-same-width-when-hiding-columns-dynamically/1440462#1440462)

Explains how to alter the RDLC file during runtime.  You could easily tie a similar function to a web service request.  The client side would request a new RDLC file from a web service, then refresh it in the report viewer control.

Not sure about #2.