# SSRS report produces blank/white spaces when column are hidden in tablix

Tags: reportingservices-2005, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

I have report developed in SSRS 2005. It is a simple and straight-forward report using a stored procedure to fetch the data and display. This report has 100 columns and there are no grouping or subreports etc.

But user has option to select/deselect the column names to show/hide on the report. When the user select to hide couple of columns report is giving me blank/white gaps when exported to pdf or any other formats.

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Can you clarify how you are hiding the columns? Via parameters?

Comment: Hi Cam,  I select a particular column header, and in the properties for visible I write expression as "=iif(parameter!name1.value = 1, True, False)".  When you preview in the RS the column is hidden if parameter!name1.value=1 but when I export the report to pdf I see the blank space.

Comment: Hi desi, I am not of much help this time. I think Frank got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure that you are hiding the row or the column of the table and not simply the fields. Check HarlingtonTheWizard's post at the following link:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=109566

Once the rows/columns are hidden, the height/width will collapse.

Comment: Hi Frank,  Thanks for sending me the link.  When i hide the column in the RS preview it seems to us that the column is collapsed when hidden but when i try to export the report to pdf, the space remains like that onlyl.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440381/ssrs-keep-a-table-the-same-width-when-hiding-columns-dynamically

Comment: sorry about that last post.  I was not correct, you don't appear to be able to hide columns in PDF export in SSRS 2005:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/531206/ssrs-2005-pdf-renderer-shows-hidden-table-column-filled-with-border-color

Comment: the accepted solution from the link 2 posts back would be a hard, but possible solution.  If you use a client-side report and read your report into memory, you have the option to write it out to the file system again and then referenced by your report dependent on what output format you are going to be using.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170667%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do not consider this as the best solution but is more of a hack but this is what I did in my situation.

1)Place a white rectangle in the desired cell. Make sure that the rectangle is white and has no borders.
2)Place the textbox inside the rectangle. Set an expression to hide and show this textbox.
3)Repeat for each cell in that column.

Therefore, when the textbox is shown it will look as normal. When the the textbox is hidden, the white rectangle will work as a "placeholder" to occupy the cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting Report property `containerwhitespace="True"`.