# Dynamic Column In SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have to design a report in which the number of columns changes according to row heading.

Whenever associated column doesn't have a value, it should be displayed for particular heading.Only fields containing values should be displayed.The report also includes static row and column name.

My problem is that I'm a novice in SSRS and unable to implement matrix report.Please elaborate in detail.

Prashant.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear at all. Why can't you implement a matrix report? Should columns that have values be displayed or not? (You indicate both options in your question.) What does your data set look like?

Comment: I think even if you could mock up a sample in Excel or something and post a screenshot, it may help give some detail. It's hard to know what exactly you're expecting from the question as it currently is.

Comment: Will this solution helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888661/how-do-i-represent-an-unknown-number-of-columns-in-ssrs/10527254#10527254

Answer (score 0):

You can take an advantage of the column visible property.

Hide/Visible it according to your needs.