# How to Add SSRS Column Programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services

I have a table Called EmployeeTypes which hold types of Employees, now i want to create a report using SSRS which will have something like this:

```
      EmployeeType1      EmployeeType2     EmployeeType3
            4                  23                2
```

where the numbers are the count of employees.

problem is how can i generate the columns programmatically like that as the EmployeeTypes Table can have many Types and expand by time?

Comment: I have the similar problem, and I have posted my solution here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888661/how-do-i-represent-an-unknown-number-of-columns-in-ssrs/10527254#10527254.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for a cross tab report, using a data set like `select count(*), employee_type from employee_table group by employee_type`.

You can use the report wizard to create a 'Matrix' report type (as opposed to a 'Tabular' report type).  The wizard will guide you through the steps to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

An SSRS report is defined by an XML file (the .RDL or .RDLC file). You could generate columns programmatically by directly modifying the XML. Not for the faint of heart, but people do it, and it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11254/SQL-Reporting-Services-with-Dynamic-Column-Reports