# Design SSRS Report when the columns list vary

Tags: dynamic, ssrs-2008

How can i design the dynamic SSRS Tabular Report when the columns list vary based on the parameter value. I mean a stored procedure returns 2 to n number of columns based on parameter value. If we have fixed number columns then there is no problem with design. But, how can i design layout if the columns list varies?

Please find my stored procedure (Dataset) below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE USP_GetReport @Param INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@Param = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT COL1
            ,COL2
            ,COL3
            ,COL4
        FROM TABLENAME
    END

<pre>
IF (@Param = 2)
BEGIN
    SELECT COL1
        ,COL2....COLn
    FROM TABLENAME
END
```

Comment: If I'm understanding the issue correctly, it seems like a repost of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888661/how-do-i-represent-an-unknown-number-of-columns-in-ssrs

Comment: Thanks,  I didn't find it before. Let me check whether it works or not...